# What is the German word for Residency (medicine)?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request

A medical residency is a period of on-site training post-med school graduation.  I am not sure if there is a direct translation for this.  All resources I could find give the normal definition.  I don't think Wohnsitz or Residenz would work.

Comment: When I lookup Wikipedia's [Residency (medical)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_(medicine)), the German counterpart is [Ärztliche Weiterbildung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84rztliche_Weiterbildung). In [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=medical+residency), as a translation of "medical residency" I find "Facharztausbildung". Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: @konst thank you!  These terms are exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: In general it's a useful trick, when a word is too specialized for a dictionary, to look it up on Wikipedia instead and check the 'languages' links.

Comment: @konst: Please do not use comments to post answers. Please write a proper answer.

Comment: Not being a doctor, I have always thought it corresponts to the [Turnus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnusarzt), but that's appearently false. Probably the best answer is "it's not really translateable due to differences in qualification systems".

Comment: @konst If that was an answer, I'd upvote it! Maybe you can add the term *Arzt in Weiterbildung* (AiW) for *resident* (a graduated physician who is engaged in residency).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast + amadeusamadeus: Sorry for potentially burying relevant information in a comment, which I would have elaborated into an answer if I knew more about medical education systems. My hope was/is that the links would be helpful to someone as a starting point for further research or for writing an actual answer.

Comment: @konst: Your comment nailed it. The old form was "Arzt im Praktikum" or "Assistenzarzt", the new one since 2004 is as you said "Arzt in Weiterbildung" or "ärztliche Weiterbildung". I wrote the answer only to realize that the merits are your's :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest "Facharztausbildung". It requires 6 years of on-site training. Afterwards a doctor can become a specialist in the particular medical area (e.g. surgeon, ENT) that was the focus of the residency.

Answer (score -1):

When you're stuck with dictionaries, which are just single word translation tools, you should try translation services that translate whole sentences like [Google translate](https://translate.google.de) or [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com).

I didn't really get what you was asking about, because I didn't know the English term *»medical residency«* (I'm a German native speaker). So I copied your question and pasted it into these two translation services, and here are the translations they created:

- https://translate.google.de

  > Eine **medizinische Residenz** ist eine Zeit der Ausbildung vor Ort nach dem Schulabschluss. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es eine direkte Übersetzung dafür gibt. Alle Ressourcen, die ich finden konnte, geben die normale Definition. Ich glaube nicht, dass Wohnsitz oder Residenz funktionieren würden .
- https://www.deepl.com

  > Eine **medizinische Facharztausbildung** ist ein Zeitraum der Ausbildung vor Ort nach dem Abschluss des Medizinstudiums. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob es dafür eine direkte Übersetzung gibt. Alle Quellen, die ich finden konnte, geben die normale Definition an. Ich glaube nicht, dass Wohnsitz oder Residenz funktionieren würde.

When I feed in only the first sentence, I get:

- https://translate.google.de

  > Ein **medizinischer Aufenthalt** ist eine Zeit der Ausbildung vor Ort nach dem Schulabschluss.
- https://www.deepl.com

  > Eine **medizinische Facharztausbildung** ist ein Zeitraum der Ausbildung vor Ort nach dem Abschluss des Medizinstudiums.

Another resource to translate some terms (mainly nouns and noun-like groups of words) is Wikipedia: Find the article that explains the term you are looking for, which in your case is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residency_(medicine) and find the word *»Deutsch«* in the left sidebar in the section *»Languages«.* Click on it, and you will land on the German version of the same article, which in our example is [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ärztliche_Weiterbildung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84rztliche_Weiterbildung). The title of this article is **Ärztliche Weiterbildung.**

So, all in all we have these translations of your term:

1. medizinische Residenz
2. medizinische Facharztausbildung (twice)
3. medizinischer Aufenthalt
4. ärztliche Weiterbildung

The focus of 1 and 3 (both of them provided by google translate) is on the local aspect, i.e. it describes *where* you are, which matches with the English term.

2 and 4 put the aspect on the education, i.e. *what* you are doing.

It strongly depends on the context which of these possibilities fits best for your needs, so it's hard to say, which of them is the best.

Comment: I don't find the use of machine translation appropriate. Answers should be informed by human intelligence. Two of the four translations are word-for-word translations that do not convey the intended meaning. The last paragraph is wrong in suggesting otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure there even is an exact counterpart to the residency in the German curriculum. I didn't do a deep dive, but the [praktisches Jahr](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studium_der_Medizin#Praktisches_Jahr) and/or the time the candidate is (used to be?) an [Arzt im Praktikum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzt_im_Praktikum) might be candidates as well.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck *Praktisches Jahr* is a requirement for graduation in Germany, while *residency* is always **post**-graduate. *Arzt im Praktikum* was post-graduate, but existed only 1988--2004 in Germany and is arguably obsolete now.

Comment: "Medizinische Facharztausbildung" seems to be the best translation. [Here](https://www.sgu.edu/blog/medical/what-to-expect-as-a-medical-resident/) is an explanation. 1.  What is medical residency? You know residency is the period of training you’ll go through after completing medical school, but it’s a little difficult to understand exactly what that means. [...] 2. How long is medical residency? The duration of postgraduate training depends on your specialty. Generally speaking, residency lasts for three to seven years.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that's, in general, bad advice. For the mapping of technical terms one should really not trust machine translation tools. It's probably far better to ask someone who's familiar with the terms and their usage in their respective context.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest the usage of "*Praktikum*" or "*Hospitation*" (or rather the verb: "*hospitieren*"). Depending on the context, the job name could also help you, which would be "*Assistenzarzt*" for this time.

Comment: Since a *residency* typically lasts 3--7 years, the terms *Praktikum* and *Hospitation* wouldn't fit for the whole time. Albeit the first year of residency in the U.S. is in fact called *internship* and first-year residents *interns*, in German (D) *Praktikum* and *Hospitation* would rather refer to the *Famulatur*. The term *Assistenzarzt* describes what most residents are, however it denominates not completely the same, because *residency* is a form of educational program for specialization, while an *Assistenzarzt* can already be a post-residency specialist.